# Probabilities , Central limit theorem

Tags: probability, central-limit-theorem, delta-method

So I am working on a problem where I have to find the approximate law of $\frac{1}{\bar{X}}$ where $X_{j}$ follow the Normal distribution law. Everything is fine up until the point I have to check the region where $\mu$ is equal to zero. Can you help me. Thus far I derived the formula

$g(\overline{X}_n)\approx N(g(\mu),\sigma^2g(\mu)'^2/n)$

Thus I ll get in the general case where $\mu\ne0$, that  $\frac{1}{\bar{X}}\approx N(\frac{1}{\mu},\frac{\sigma^2}{n\mu^2})$

Thank you in advance, for your contribution

Answer (score 1):

If $X_1,\ldots, X_n$ are i.i.d. $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$,
$$
\bar{X}_n\sim N(\mu, \sigma^2/n).
$$
Thus, the exact distribution of $\bar{X}_n^{-1}$ is known. Specifically, the pdf of $\bar{X}_n^{-1}$ is given by:
$$
f(z)=\frac{\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma z^2}\exp\!\left(-\frac{n}{2\sigma^2}\left(\frac{1}{z}-\mu\right)^2\right).
$$

Answer (score -1):

> I have to find the **approximate law of** $1/\overline{X}$

Applying Delta method, as you did, you get that

$$\frac{1}{\overline{X}_n}\dot{\sim}N\left(\frac{1}{\mu};\frac{\sigma^2}{n\mu^4}  \right)$$

this because

$$[g'(\mu)]^2=\frac{1}{\mu^4}$$

Comment: yeah but if $\mu$ goes to zero then what?